# App to apply color to text across apps in OS X

Tags: macos, hotkeys

I am looking for a way to hotkey a change in color of highlighted text across a broad range of applications on OS X 10.9.

This could be:

- a small app that acts on selected text (something like [Liquid](http://liquid.info))
- an applescript or other programmatic solution; this can be hotkeyed using the utility [Keymando](http://keymando.com/)
- anything else

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about other applications, but you could use a script like this with TextEdit:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "TextEdit"
    set {x, y} to value of attribute "AXSelectedTextRange" of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
end tell
tell application "TextEdit"
    set color of characters x thru y of document 1 to {65535, 0, 0}
end tell
```

Comment: Thanks Lri. I think I won't have a problem creating individual scripts for many different applications, but I'm looking specifically for something that can be used across all applications-- like a Service or something. Any idea on how to adapt this?